# Upgrade from Jboss 6 to wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, jsf-2.2, wildfly-10

After upgrading from Jboss 6 to wildfly 10, I had this exception for all value attribute that use method call in the managed bean
As example:

```
<h:inputText value="#{controller.value(cat,subCat)}">
```

Managed bean contains

```
public String value(String x ,String y){
 //Code here to return value..
}
public void setValue(String x){
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: ... @106,81 value="#{controller.value(cat,subCat)}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:136)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832)
... 63 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:228)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
... 64 more
```

Comment: So you used jsf 2.2 in jboss and there this code worked?

Comment: @Kukeltje For Jboss 6 I used JSF 2.1 and I also downgrade JSFimplementation to 2.1 in Wildfly and still had the exception